# Finding A Proper Subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Exhibit a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is not cyclic

Let $H$ be the subgroup of all reduced fraction whose denominator is odd. I already proved that this is a subgroup, and I also showed that if a subgroup $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic, then its generator is of the form $\frac{1}{n}$

By way of contradiction, suppose that $H$ is cyclic with generator $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ must be odd, and let $p$ be some positive odd number. Then certainly $\frac{1}{p} \in H$ and therefore $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{m}{n}$ for some integer $m$. Then $n = pm$. Since $\frac{m}{n}$ is a reduced fraction, they cannot have any common factors, implying that $m|n$ cannot be. Therefore, $p|n$. But this says every odd number divides $n$ and so every odd number is a factor of $n$. This impossible because $n+2$ is odd yet it cannot divide $n$.

Does this sound right? It probably be cleaned up slightly; I am sure I am missing some logical subtleties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re working quite a bit too hard. Once you have $n=pm$ with $p$ an integer, you’ve shown that $m\mid n$. Since $p>0$, this is possible only if $p=1$, and you can rule that out by choosing $p$ to be an odd integer greater than $1$. Then you have your contradiction already at this point, and you can get rid of everything that follows it.

An alternative argument is to observe that $\frac{m}n\ge\frac1n$ when $m$ is positive, and $\frac{m}n\le 0$ when $m$ is negative, so $H\cap\left(0,\frac1n\right)=\varnothing$. But $\frac1{n+2}\in H\cap\left(0,\frac1n\right)$, and you have a contradiction.

Comment: So you are saying $n = pm$ implies $m|n$? Wouldn't this be an immediate contradiction, because $m$ and $n$ would then have common factors? So, should I just take $p$ to be any odd number that doesn't divide $n$? I guess i don't see how $n=pm$ implies $m|n$ and therefore $p$ must be $1$.

Comment: @user193319: It’s an immediate contradiction unless $m=n=1$. You need to rule out that possibility, either by observing that in that case $\frac1n$ generates $\Bbb Z$, not $H$, or as I suggested, by choosing $p\ge 3$. \\ The existence of an integer $p$ such that $n=pm$ is the *definition* of $m\mid n$.